# C# Edge Webdriver - download file issue

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have a lot of problems with chromedriver like "devtoolsactiveport file doesn't exist", so I decided to change driver do Edge, but I also have a problem with download files. I get a prompts that file can be unsafe. I solve that problem by adding to registry new key

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings
```

with entry #1:

```
{ "domains": ["*"], "file_extension": "xml" }
```

But it allows to download xml from any domain. I would like to know if it possible to restrict domain to specific ip range. I execute tests on azure virtual machine, my app is also on that azure but on separate machine. When i set up domain value to "*10.9.*" it doesn't work.

My app ip adress is for example 10.9.144.11 and its different on each iteration of tests

Answer (score 1):

As the [Filter format for URL list-based policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/edge-learnmmore-url-list-filter%20format#the-filter-format) described:

> A single IP Address Literal hostname may be specified, but wildcarding
> is not supported for an IP Address Literal hostname.

Therefore, you need to configure a specific IP address every time.